# Something is forcing responses to have cache-control: private in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, web-config, http-headers, cache-control

I have this in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <clear />
              <add name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=30,public" />
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

But when I load the page, this is the response header:

```
Cache-Control: private,max-age=30,public
```

It is an ASP.NET MVC application, the controller has no cache directives specified anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, IIS appends headers (with a comma) from the customHeaders section.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just can't figure out where the 'private' is coming from.  It's very frustrating!

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue, but since we're using DNN, I'm assuming it comes from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cache-control: no-store, must-revalidate not sent to client browser in IIS7 + ASP.NET MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443932/cache-control-no-store-must-revalidate-not-sent-to-client-browser-in-iis7-as)

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime sendCacheControlHeader="false" /> 
 </system.web>
```

Let us know how it goes.

Jason

Comment: Works for me on IIS 8, as does this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22468386/318411