# How to replace private from cache-control security header value with my custom value in asp.net running on iis server

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, model-view-controller, cache-control

I have to customized cache-control value for security reason,When I add new value in custom header for cache-control ,it will get append to private.

Comment: Read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/247404/how-to-modify-the-cache-control-http-header-when-you-use-iis), hope it will be helpful

Comment: try to add `<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
< /configuration>` in web.confg fie. you could also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224561/iis-asp-net-responds-with-cache-control-private-for-all-requests)

Comment: I got my answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908115/something-is-forcing-responses-to-have-cache-control-private-in-iis7/33065747  It will not allow to send default value for cache control in response header